# Simple algebra question - proving $a^2+b^2 \geqslant 2ab$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How to prove that $$a^2+b^2 \geqslant 2ab$$
is true, where $a$ and $b$ are both real numbers?

Comment: See also [Show that for all real numbers $a$ and $b$, $ab \le (1/2)(a^2+b^2)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943994/show-that-for-all-real-numbers-a-and-b-ab-le-1-2a2b2)