# Show using the definition of limit that $\lim_{ (x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{ (1-\cos(xy))\sin y}{(x^2+y^2) }= 0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

can you help me with this excercise.

Show using the definition of limit that

$$\lim_{ (x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{ (1-\cos(xy))\sin y}{(x^2+y^2) }= 0$$

> **Definition of limit:**
>
> $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y) =L$ if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$ exist $\delta>0$ such that if $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\delta$ then $|f(x,y)-L|<\epsilon$.

Hi 
I´ve tried this,

For taylor series.

Given $\epsilon>0$, find $\delta>0$ such that if

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$$ then $$\bigg|\frac{(1-\cos xy)\sin y}{x^2+y^2}\bigg|<\epsilon$$
\begin{align*}
\bigg|\frac{(1-\cos xy)\sin y}{x^2+y^2}\bigg| & = \bigg|\frac{(1-1-\frac{x^2y^2}{2}+\frac{x^4y^4}{24})(y-\frac{y^3}{6}+\frac{y^5}{120})}{x^2+y^2}\bigg|\\
& =\bigg|\frac{(-\frac{x^2y^2}{2}+\frac{x^4y^4}{24})(y-\frac{y^3}{6}+\frac{y^5}{120})}{x^2+y^2}\bigg|
\end{align*}

Then what do I do?

Comment: Please review [ask].  While Math.SE is an excellent Q&A site for all levels of mathematical study, the Community as a whole does not wish it to be a let's-do-your-homework-for-you site.  What's the difference?  Well, we ask that you explain what you tried, and especially identify where you ran into a difficulty or misunderstanding.  Then your Readers will be better prepared to write responses that get you on track to do your own assignments.

Answer (score 4):

We need only use the inequality $\sin x<x$ for $x>0$ along with the trigonometric identity $\sin^2 x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$.

Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
|1-\cos xy|&=|2\sin^2(xy/2)|\\\\
&\le\frac12(xy)^2\\\\
&\le \frac14(x^2+y^2)^2
\end{align}$$

along with

$$\begin{align}
|\sin y| &\le |y|\\\\
&\le(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{(1-\cos xy)\sin y}{x^2+y^2}-0\right|&\le\frac{\frac14(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}{x^2+y^2} \\\\
&=\frac14(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}<\delta = (4\epsilon)^{1/3}$.

Comment: thanks,, but why do you say $\frac12(xy)^2<
 \frac14(x^2+y^2)^2$

Comment: @MathYobani It is basically AM-GM inequality for two variables. See [Simple algebra question - proving $a^2+b^2 \geqslant 2ab$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241741/simple-algebra-question-proving-a2b2-geqslant-2ab) and several other posts on this site.