# Show that $2 xy < x^2 + y^2$ for $x$ is not equal to $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Show that $2 xy < x^2 + y^2$ for $x$ is not equal to $y$.

Comment: BTW [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_inequality) is a generalization of this.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470221/prove-the-inequality-xy-leq-frac12x2y2

Answer (score 20):

Note that $(x-y)^2 \ge 0$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$, with equality only when $x=y$. Now expand $(x-y)^2$.

A surprisingly large number of useful inequalities follow from the simple observation that any square is non-negative.

Answer (score 11):

If $x\neq y$ then without loss of generality we can assume that $x>y$  $x-y>0\Rightarrow (x-y)^2>0\Rightarrow x^2-2xy+y^2>0\Rightarrow x^2+y^2>2xy$

Comment: If you're taking this approach, you should say something about when $x-y<0$.

Comment: @Clayton I don't think so. $x$ and $y$ are variables, they can always change their values to satisfy the condition defined/explained/derived above.

Comment: then WLOG we can say..maybe you should mention it to the OP..

Comment: btw, you don't use that x > y, you actually use x != y

Answer (score 2):

Let $$y=x+a$$ $$a \neq 0$$ then $$2xy=2x(x+a)=2x^2+2ax<2x^2+2ax+a^2$$

see that the difference is exactly 'a' squared.