# Proving an alternative norm on Sobolev space is equivalent to usual norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I have this exercice and my problel is only in item 4, and i will desespere.

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n).$

1-  Why the equation $\Delta u - u = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ admits a unique solution $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

2- Prove that there exist a constant $C \geq 0$ that $||u||_{H^1} \leq C ||f||_{L^2}$.

3- Prove that there exist a constant $M \geq 0$ that for all $u \in H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have $||u||_{H^2} \leq M (||u||_{L^2})$.

4- We assume that $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2} \overline{\dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_j^2}} \,\mathrm dx + \lambda \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u \overline{v} \,\mathrm dx$$
represente an scalar product to $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $\lambda > 0.$

- Prove that this scalar product is equivalent to the classical scalar product to $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

  We denote the norm defined by this scalar product $\|\cdot\|_*$.
  I wan't to prove the existance of two constantes positives $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $$c_1 \|u\|_{H^2} \leq \|u\|_* \leq c_2 \|u\|_{H^2}.$$ But i can't prove this two inequality.

Okay, so my work for item 4 is:

to prove the second inequality: we have from item 3) that: $||u||_{H^2} \leq M (||u||_{L^2} + ||\Delta u||_{L^2})$ and we know that $\Delta u = \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}$ so $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n \displaystyle\int \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i} \overline{\dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_j}} dx = \displaystyle\int |\Delta u|^2 dx = ||\Delta u||^2_{L^2}$$
but my problem is to use item 3 to deduce the second inequality.

To prove the first inequality, we have $$||u||^2_{H^2} =||\Delta u||^2_{L^2} + ||\nabla u||^2_{L^2} + ||u||^2_{L^2}$$
and we have by Holder and Young inequalities,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i,j=1}^n \displaystyle\int \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2} \overline{\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_j^2}} dx & \leq \sum_{i,j=1}^n ||\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}||^2_{L^2} . ||\dfrac{\partial^2 \overline{u}}{\partial x_j^2}||^2_{L^2}\\
& \leq \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j=1}^n (||\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}||^2_{L^2} + ||\dfrac{\partial^2 \overline{u}}{\partial x_j^2}||^2)\\
& \leq \sum_{i,j=1}^n (||\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}||^2_{L^2} + ||\dfrac{\partial^2 \overline{u}}{\partial x_j^2}||^2)
\end{align*}

and and I'm stuck for the rest

i have difficulties just for the last step, help me please to finish this exercice
Thank's for help.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [MSE quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Comment: i edit my message. can you help me please?

Comment: Thanks for providing context. What did you try to do so far for part 4? (Please [edit] the question to include your work.)

Comment: i edit my message to write my work. Can you help me please.

Comment: Thank you! This way we can provide you optimal assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The statement in item 3 looks wrong. Should it be $\|u\|_{H^2} \leq M (\|u\|_{L^2}+\|\Delta u\|_{L^2})$? This is the inequality you quote in the sentence "we have from item 3)".

The norm defined by the inner product with $\lambda$ is:
$$\|u\|_*^2 = \|\Delta u\|_{L^2}^2+ \lambda \|u\|^2_{L^2} \tag1$$
According to your post, the "classical norm" is 
$$\|u\|^2_{H^2} =\|\Delta u\|^2_{L^2} + \|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2} + \|u\|^2_{L^2}\tag2$$
We have  the inequality $\|u\|_*^2 \le (1+\lambda) \|u\|^2_{H^2} $  just as a matter of algebra. In the converse direction, the issue is to estimate  $\|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2}$ from above using $\|\Delta u\|_{L^2}^2$ and $\|u\|^2_{L^2}$. This is done by integration by parts followed by [the famous $xy\le x^2+y^2$ inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/357272):
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \nabla u\cdot \nabla u = - \int_{\mathbb R^n} u\,\Delta u \le \int_{\mathbb R^n}(|u|^2+|\Delta u|^2) \tag3$$
(Strictly speaking, one proves (3) for smooth compactly supported functions first, and then uses the fact that they are dense in $H^2(\mathbb R^n)$.) Once we have (3), the rest   again reduces to algebra:
$$\|u\|^2_{H^2} \le (2+2\lambda^{-1})\|u\|_*^2$$

Comment: by 3 we have $$||\Delta u||^2 + ||\nabla u||^2 + ||u||^2 \leq 2(||\Delta u||^2 + ||\Delta u||^2)$$ how we deduce the last relation with $\lambda$?

Comment: I don't found $$\|u\|^2_{H^2} \le (2+2\lambda^{-1})\|u\|_*^2$$ i found $$\|u\|^2_{H^2} \le (2+\lambda)\|u\|_*^2$$ what's the good result?