# If $a$ and $b$ are the roots of $z^2 - 2z + 4 = 0$ then what is $a^n + b^n + ab$ ($n$ is a natural number)?

Tags: roots

I don't know how to solve this question, any help would be appreciate it.

If $z^2 - 2z + 4 = 0$, then what is the result of this $a^n + b^n + ab$ ($n$ is a natural number, $a$ and $b$ are the roots of that equation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$z=1\pm\sqrt3i=2\left(\cos\dfrac\pi3\pm i\sin\dfrac\pi3\right)$$

Using  [de Moivre's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMoivresIdentity.html),

$$z^n=2^n\left(\cos\dfrac{n\pi}3\pm i\sin\dfrac{n\pi}3\right)$$

Comment: awesome, outstanding, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** You know that $a^2=2a-4$. Thus $a^3 = 2a^2-4a = \dots$

**Hint 2:** You know that $z^2-2z+4 = (z-a)(z-b)=z^2-(a+b)z+ab$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$z=1\pm\sqrt{3}i=-2w,-2w^2$$ where $w$ is a complex cube root of $1$

$\implies ab=4$

Need to deal $\displaystyle n\equiv0,1,2\pmod3$ separately.

Comment: Thanks, I got here: (1+isqrt(3))^(n) + (1-isqrt(3))^(n) + 4, now could you help me a little bit more?

Comment: @Dwonvoter, please pinpoint the mistake

Comment: while i am not the down voter, I think the comemnt on your answer here is a valid reason for the down vote. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357272/how-can-i-prove-that-xy-leq-x2y2/357275#357275

Comment: @Lost1, not sure if I've understood your statement properly.

Comment: dude, you have so much reputation points, yet you write, not 1, but TWO answers to a relatively trivial question. I think you can make better contributions by answering some hard questions. This is precisely what the downvoter on your other post said. While I did not down vote this, I think this is true.

Comment: @Lost1, which "other post"? Anyway, hopefully one can easily understand the difference between the two methods as well.