# How to show for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $|x|\leqslant 1+x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

How to show for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $$|x|\leqslant 1+x^2$$

I can show $2|x|\leq 1+x^2$, but how to show the above?

Comment: What you can show is already stronger than what you want to show: $|x| \le 2|x|$.

Comment: This can be also considered as a special case of $xy\le x^2+y^2$, see [How can I prove that $xy\leq x^2+y^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/357272) and other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/357272).

Comment: Here is a link to the discussion of this question in the [reopen request thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today/30395#30395).

Comment: For people who are wondering how to get the inequality $2|x|\le 1+x^2$ mentioned in the post, see here (for example): [How to prove that $x^2 +1 \geq 2x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2424538)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that
$$
2|x|\leq 1+x^2 \quad \implies \quad |x|\leq \frac{1+x^2}2 \le 1+x^2.
$$

Answer (score 2):

For real $x,|x|^2=x^2$ and $$4|x|^2-4|x|+4=(2|x|-1)^2+3\ge3$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $|x|=t$ ;

You get : $$|x|\leqslant 1+x^2 \implies t^2-t+1 \ge 0$$

Now, the discriminant of $t^2-t+1$ is :
 $$b^2-4ac=1-4=-3 <0$$ Therefore;

$$ t^2-t+1 \ge 0 ~\forall ~t \in \mathbb R^+$$
Hence :

$$|x|\leqslant 1+x^2 ~~\forall ~x \in \mathbb R$$

Comment: Though in the section right after "You get" both implications are true, technically the one you are interested in is "$\Longleftarrow$", not "$\implies$".

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I think there should be a bi-implies arrow, instead of a single sided arrow.Right?

Comment: Yes, it is true that the two inequations are equivalent. My point is that you've stated only the implication which does not serve your purpose, since you want to use the fact that the second is always true to prove that the first is always true.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes, of couse they are.

Answer (score 2):

Since $|x|\geq 0$, you have $|x|\leq 2|x|$, and so by inserting the inequality you know $2|x|\leq 1+x^2$ you'd get the desires $|x|\leq 2|x|\leq 1+x^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'inserting the inequality'?

Comment: The transitive rule.

Answer (score 2):

by $AM-GM$ we have $$1+x^2\geq 2|x|\geq |x|$$

Answer (score 0):

Well you've actually proven something stronger.

Since $|x|\ge 0$ and $2>1$, then $|x|\le 2|x| \le 1 + x^2$.

But, if you want to be thorough.

$(|x|-1)^2\ge 0$

$x^2-2|x|+1\ge 0$

$x^2 +1\ge 2|x|$

$x^2+1\ge 2|x| \ge |x|$.

That's all.