# How to prove that $x^2 +1 \geq 2x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, quadratics

I am trying to prove that $x^2 +1 \geq 2x$ without using circular logic (meaning first assuming that this inequality is true and then moving to the $2x$ to the left side and factoring it). Thanks.

Comment: $(x-1)^2 > 0$ ..

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit for |x|>1

Comment: It's not true for $x=1$. You can show $x^2+1\geq 2x$, however.

Comment: What you should actually be doing is showing that $x^2 + 1 \geq 2x$ is equivalent to $(x-1)^2 \geq 0$, which is true. This is not circular.

Comment: okay sorry not equal to 1 it should be.

Comment: This might sound kind of silly but you might be able to use induction to prove this is true for integers. However for real numbers that proof would not hold.

Answer (score 15):

$$x^2 + 1 = x^2 - 2x + 1 + 2x = \underbrace{(x-1)^2}_{\geq 0} + 2x \geq 2x$$

Comment: beautiful...........!!!!

Answer (score 8):

Work backwards . . .

\begin{align*}
&(x-1)^2 \ge 0&&\text{[since squares are nonnegative]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2-2x+1 \ge 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2 + 1 \ge 2x\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Alternatively, work forwards, but use $\iff$ . . .
\begin{align*}
&x^2+1 \ge 2x
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;];\;\;\;
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x^2-2x + 1 \ge 0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&(x-1)^2 \ge 0\\[4pt]
&\text{which is true since squares are nonnegative.}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
This allows the argument to be reversed without actually reversing it.

But to use the $\iff$ version, you need to be careful to make sure that each line is equivalent to the previous one (i.e., each implies the other).

Answer (score 4):

If $x \le 0$, it is true.

If $x=1$, there is equality.

If $x>1$, you put $x=1+\epsilon $ with $\epsilon>0$.

then
$$x^2+1=(1+\epsilon)^2+1$$
$$=1+\epsilon^2+2\epsilon+1$$
$$=2 (1+\epsilon)+\epsilon^2>2x $$

If $0 <x <1$ put $y=\frac {1}{x}>1 $.
then
$$y^2+1=\frac {1}{x^2}+1$$
$$=\frac {x^2+1}{x^2}>2\frac {1}{x} $$
$$\implies 1+x^2>2x $$
Done!

Answer (score 3):

$x^2 +1 \geq 2x\iff x^2 -2x+1 \geq0$

let $f(x):= x^2 -2x+1 \implies f'(x)= 2x-2 $

$f'(x)=0 \implies x=1$

$f$ is decreasing over $(-\infty,1]$ and increasing over $[1,+\infty)$ and $f(1)=0$ so $f(x)\ge 0$

So we have proved $f(x)=x^2 -2x+1\ge 0$ so $x^2 +1 \geq 2x$

Answer (score 1):

*Proof*: $$\begin{align} x^2 + 1 &\geqslant 2x \\ \iff x^2 + 1 - 2x &\geqslant 0 \\ \iff x^2 + 1^2 - 2\cdot x\cdot 1 &\geqslant 0 \\ \iff (x - 1)^2 &\geqslant 0,\end{align}$$ as desired.$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\,\,\,\,\,\,\Box$

Comment: Pardon me if I'm wrong, but $P\Rightarrow Q$ doesn't necessarily imply $Q\Rightarrow P$. For example, $(x=\pi)\Rightarrow(\sin(x)=0)$ but the converse isn't always true. For instance, $\sin(x)=0$ could mean $x=0$ or $x=\pi$, etc. So I think there needs to be another step to show that $x-1\geq0\Rightarrow x^2+1\geq 2x$.

Comment: Also, $(x-1)^2\geq0\Rightarrow (x\geq 1)$ isn't necessarily true (take $x=0$ for example). You've got to consider both sides of the parabola.

Comment: Woah sorry about that. I am going to re-edit.

Comment: @GeorgeN.Missailidis No I will