# How do I prove $2xy ≤ x^2+y^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm quite new at calculus, how could I prove:

$$2xy ≤ x^2 + y^2$$

I just can end up in $(xy)^{1/2} ≤ (x+y)/2$. And even though I know that this is true too, I don't know how to prove it either.
Thank you in advance :D

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 -2xy \geq0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Observe the fact that for any real $x,y$ that $(x - y)^2 \ge 0$. Is there anything you can do to that inequality to get you to the result you wish to prove?

Comment: See also: [Prove the inequality $|xy|\leq\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/470221) and [Show that $2 xy < x^2 + y^2$ for $x$ is not equal to $y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/320244)

Answer (score 1):

The trivial inequality $a^2 \geq 0$ is true for any $a$. Im particular, it must be true that

$$ (x-y)^2 \geq 0 $$

But, $(x-y)^2 = x^2 - 2xy + y^2 $. Therefore, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 0 \leq (x-y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 - 2xy $$
which yields the result.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2 \geq 0$$
$$(a \pm b)^2 \geq 0$$
$$a^2\pm 2ab+b^2 \geq 0$$
$$a^2+b^2 \geq \mp 2ab$$
In particular, using $(a-b)$, we get the following.
$$\boxed{a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab}$$