# Determining an ellipse inscribed in a rectangle given its tangent point at one of the sides

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Given a rectangle $PQRS$ with vertices $P(0,0), Q(a, 0), R(a,b), S(0, b)$ I want to determine the equation of the ellipse inscribed in it, and touching it bottom edge at $T(c, 0)$ where $0 \lt c \lt a $.

My attempt is summarized as follows:  First, from symmetry of the ellipse with respect to the rectangle, then the center of the ellipse will be at $C = \dfrac{1}{2} (a, b ) $.  Second, using matrix-vector notation, let $ p = [x,y ]^T $ be a point on this inscribed  ellipse, then $p$ satisfies the ellipse equation which is

$ (p - C)^T A (p - C) = 1 \hspace{12pt}(1) $

for some symmetric positive definite $2 \times 2 $ matrix $A$.  Since $A$ is symmetric, it is determined by three scalars which are $A_{11}, A_{12}, A_{22} $

Since the point $T (c, 0)$ is on the ellipse then

$ (T - C)^T A (T - C) = 1 \hspace{12pt} (2)$

Tangency to the bottom side, tells us that the gradient of the ellipse (which points in the outward normal vector direction) is along the $-j$ vector, where $j$ is the unit vector in the positive $y$ axis direction.

Therefore, let's first compute the gradient.  It is given by

$ g(p) = 2 A (p - C) \hspace{12pt} (3)$

From the above, we have

$ A(T - C) = - \alpha j $,  for some $\alpha \gt 0 \hspace{12pt}(4) $

From this last equation it follows that

$ T - C = - \alpha A^{-1} j \hspace{12pt}(5) $

Substituting this into the equation of the ellipse, we find that $\alpha$ is given by

$ \alpha = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{j^T A^{-1} j}} \hspace{12pt}(6) $

Pre-multiplying both sides of equation $(5)$ by $j^T$ , we get

$ j^T (T - C) = 0 - \dfrac{b}{2} = - \dfrac{ j^T A^{-1} j }{ \sqrt{ j^T A^{-1} j } } = - \sqrt{j^T A^{-1} j } \hspace{12pt} (7) $

Now, $j^T A^{-1} j = {A^{-1}}_{(22)} \hspace{12pt} (8) $

Now I am stuck in trying to find the elements $A_{11}, A_{12}, A_{22} $.

Equation (2) gives one linear equation in these three unknowns.  Taking the first component of Equation (4) gives another linear equation in $A_{11}$, and $A_{12} $.  Equations (7),(8) state that

$ (A^{-1})_{22} = \bigg(\dfrac{b}{2}\bigg)^2 \hspace{12pt}(9) $

which is basically saying that

$ \dfrac{ A_{11}}{A_{11}A_{22} - A_{12}^2 }  = \bigg(\dfrac{b}{2}\bigg)^2 $

But how can I solve these three equations?  That's where I am stuck.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:

Thanks to a comment by @Ethan Bolker, I've realised that that, in the above, I did not use any information about the width of the rectangle, i.e. the input parameter $a$.  So we have to somehow find the tangency point of the inscribed ellipse with the left or right side.  Since the given rectangle is an affine transformation of a square (a dilation in the $x$ and $y$) and since by inspection of an ellipse inscribed in a square, it is clear (without proof) that the ratio the bottom tangent point distance from the left bottom corner to the width $a$ is the same as the ratio as the left tangent point of the inscribed ellipse distance from the left bottom corner to the height $b$.  Thus if the left tangent point if $L(0, d)$ then

$ \dfrac{d}{b} = \dfrac{c}{a} \hspace{12pt}(10)$

Now apply the same logic in the above analysis, we deduce that

$ L - C = - \beta A^{-1} i \hspace{12pt} (11)$

where $i$ is the unit vector along the positive $x$ axis.  And using the same reasoning as above, we deduce that

$ \beta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ i^T A^{-1} i }} \hspace{12pt}(12)$

Pre-multiplying $(11)$ with $i^T$

$ i^T (L - C) = 0 - \dfrac{a}{2} = - \sqrt{i^T A^{-1} i } \hspace{12pt}(13) $

Now, using either $(5)$ or $(11)$, we have an equation isolating $A^{-1}_{(12)} $

Using $(5)$,

$i^T (T - C) = c - \dfrac{a}{2} = - \dfrac{i^T A^{-1} j }{\sqrt{j^T A^{-1} j }} \hspace{12pt}(14) $

And alternatively, using $(11)$

$ j^T (L - C) = \dfrac{bc}{a} - \dfrac{b}{2} = - \dfrac{ j^T A^{-1} i }{\sqrt{i^T A^{-1} i}} \hspace{12pt}(15)$

We can now use equations $(9)$ , we can solve immediately for $A^{-1}_{(22)} $, and from $(13)$ we find $A^{-1}_{(11)} $, and finally, using either $(14)$ or $(15)$ we can find $A^{-1}_{(12)} $.

That is,

$ A^{-1}_{(22)} =\bigg(\dfrac{b}{2}\bigg)^2 \hspace{12pt}(16) $

$ A^{-1}_{(11)} =\bigg(\dfrac{a}{2}\bigg)^2 \hspace{12pt}(17) $

$ A^{-1}_{(12)} =- \bigg(c - \dfrac{a}{2}\bigg) \dfrac{b}{2} \hspace{12pt}(18) $

Now $A^{-1}$ is determined, therefore $A$ is determined.

I appreciate any alternative methods to determine the ellipse.

**UPDATE**:  I applied the above method to a rectangle with $a = 12, b = 7$ and $c = 4$ and got the ellipse shown in the figure below

[image]

Comment: I haven't thought this through, but here's an idea. If you can solve your problem for a  square centered at the origin with sides parallel to the axes you can shift and scale the solution to get what you need. That configuration might have fewer parameters and lead to easier equations.

Comment: Yes.  I like this idea.  Symmetry of the square when extended to the rectangle means that the tangency point on the left or right sides are known.  This should give the solution.

Comment: There’s rather more to this problem than I first realized. Don‘t you suppose, @EthanBolker , that an ellipse inscribed in a square always has its axes along the diagonals? Maybe it would even make things easier to put the corners of the square on the axes, so the ellipses inscribed would now be in the high-school student’s favorite position…

Comment: @Lubin Nice observation. I was imagining where the other two tangencies had to live and sort of felt (but didn't think through) that the axes had to be on the diagonals.  So yes, put the corners of the square at $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$ and the known point of tangency at $(t, 1-t)$. Solve for the ellipse and scale, translate and rotate to where you want it.

Comment: Thanks @EthanBolker.  I was wondering if you could write these ideas in a solution and post it.  I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3926884/339790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First method.

We know the equation must be of the form
$$
\alpha(x-x_C)^2+\beta(x-x_C)(y-y_C)+\gamma(y-y_C)^2=1,
$$
where $C=(a/2,b/2)$ is the centre.
We already know the coordinates of two points of the ellipse:
$$
T=(c,0),\quad L=(0,bc/a),
$$
we need another one to find coefficients $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$. It's easy to find the coordinates of point $D$, which is an intersection between diagonal $PR$ and the ellipse (see figure below), because:
$$
CP:CD=CD:CM,
$$
where $M=\big(c/2,bc/(2a)\big)$ is the midpoint of $TL$. This property is easily verified for a circle, and is still valid for an ellipse, because stretching preserves ratios on a line. We thus get:
$$
D=\left({1-\sqrt{1-c/a}\over2}a, {1-\sqrt{1-c/a}\over2}b \right).
$$
Plugging the coordinates of $T$, $L$ and $D$ into the equation, we can solve for $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

[image]

Second Method.

If $U$ is an intersection of the ellipse with a line through $C$, parallel to $PQ$, then $CU$ is a semi-diameter conjugated with $CT$. Length $CU$ can be found from another property of conjugate diameters:

$$
\left({LH\over CU}\right)^2+\left({CH\over CT}\right)^2=1,
$$
where $H$ is on $CT$ and $LH\parallel PQ$.

From that, one can find the coordinates of $U$ and write a parametric equation for a generic point $A(t)$ on the ellipse:
$$
A(t)=C+(U-C)\cos t+(T-C)\sin t.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Partial solution in response to a comment.

Inscribe an ellipse in the square with vertices $(\pm 1, 0), (0, \pm 1)$. The ellipse will have equation
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1
$$
and the slope will be given by
$$
\frac{2xdx}{a^2} + \frac{2ydy}{b^2} = 0.
$$

We want the ellipse that goes through the point $(s,t)$ where $s+t = 1$ and to have slope $dy = -dx$ at that point.

Therefore
$$
\frac{s^2}{a^2} + \frac{t^2}{b^2} = 1
$$
and
$$
\frac{s}{a^2} - \frac{t}{b^2} = 0.
$$
You can solve the second of these equations together with $s+t=1$ to find a relation between $a^2$ and $b^2$ to use along with the first equation to find
$a^2$ and $b^2$.